# Sintara rspec test got 404 when testing subclassing subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sinatra

I am testing sinatra very base `GET`, but i got 404 error in rspec, with brower it works fine.

**config.ru**

```
map('/books'){run BooksController} #another application just for books
map('/'){run Api}
```

**Api.rb**

```
class Api < Sinatra::Base end;
```

**BooksController.rb**

```
class BooksController < Api
   namespace '/api/v1' do
     get '/books' do
       "books"
     end
   end
end
```

**books_controller_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe BooksController do
describe "Get Index" do
    it "/books" do
      get "/books/api/v1/books", {access_token:user1.access_token}
      expect(last_response.status).to eq 200
      expect(last_response.body).to eq "books"
    end
  end
end
```

**error**:

```
1) BooksController Get Index /books
     Failure/Error: expect(last_response.status).to eq 200

       expected: 200
            got: 404

       (compared using ==)
```

But http://127.0.0.1:9393/books/api/v1/books works fine in my browser.

The `shotgun`(like rackup) output when access by browser:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2016:14:48:05 +0800] "GET /books/api/v1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6 0.0089
```

**EDIT:** works fine from browser in `test` environment too. As below:
[image]

**EIDT**:when i out put `last_request.url` i got:

```
 "http://example.org/books/api/v1/books"
```

i have thought it's the domain name but when i test `Api`'s GET, i got the same host url like `http://example.org/api/v1.2/events`, but the test can pass.

Any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it appear in your development server output, and if so, post it here.

Comment: edited, i access the url from my browser works fine.

Comment: What about when you access it in your test?

Comment: Can you post that request too?

Comment: See the picture uploaded.

Comment: That's not the request. Perhaps you are not getting one?

Comment: I think it is request, i changed the test server port it do works. If it works in browser the status code is 200 too i think. Here is what added in my log file:

Comment: >127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2016:15:08:09 +0800] "GET /books/api/v1/books HTTP/1.1" 200 5 0.0018

Comment: So you are replying with a 200, yet rspec says it's a 404? Try printing out the contents of `last_response.body`. Maybe that will tell you something.

Comment: yes, i know it's url not found, just not sure why

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a new controller in your spec like this:

```
def app
  BooksController.new
end
```